# cURL performance much slower than method execution

Tags: php, curl

I have one call to api in my application via cURL to my other application, the code looks like this:

```
$target = 'api/someMethod';

$url = self :: buildUrl($target);
    $paramString = self :: buildParamString(array(
            'request' => $request,
            'partner' => $_SESSION['DataPartner'],
            'token' => $_SESSION['DataToken']
    ));

    $t = microtime(true);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $paramString,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 600,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
    ));
    $curlResponse = curl_exec($curl);
    Log :: i(microtime(true) - $t); // ~400ms
```

This cURL call takes about 400ms. The problem is that the method it retrieves data from:

```
public function someMethod() {
   $t = microtime(true);
   // create the response, some SQL, etc
   Log :: i(microtime(true) - $t); // ~20ms
   echo $response;
}
```

Takes about 20ms to run. So cURL executes in 400ms, but the method it retrieves data from executes in 20ms.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the curl execution is always going to be slower than the method alone, at least 1 ms more ;). I don't see that much of slow difference in your case. If you sum the request time, network, the server response, and all that that will give you at least 200ms in a very strong setup server enviroment, so, those 400ms, I think is normal.